# Programmable Power Supply Unit in OEM version

Tags: power-supply, dc

I need to integrate a Power Supply Unit with three DC outputs into a single product (could also be 3 independent PSU's).

I need to generate three DC voltages up to 300V, and monitor the current in the `nA` range (up to few hundreds), which means the application is very low power. I have been using these [Delta Elektronika](https://www.delta-elektronika.nl/en/products/dc-power-supplies-300w-es300-series.html), but they are not easy to integrate into a stand alone device.

I am trying to understand whether there are **any OEM vendors** for these kind of devices, or perhaps there can't be any because of safety markings?

Comment: Do you plan to sense on low or high side?

Comment: In the low side

Comment: If you're only going up to a few hundreds of nA, you could roll your own, chargepump or flyback

Comment: You could ask Delta Elektronika if they can provide their PSUs on an OEM basis.

Comment: @GrahamNye, indeed, I have already asked. I was wondering why I haven't come across anyone having it as a standard product in their catalogs

Comment: Simple shunt resistor sensing?

Comment: Could you edit your question to say you've already asked Delta and also add any other avenues you've already researched so we don't duplicate your work? Your Delta link takes us to a page for a 30 V PSU, not a 300 V PSU.

Answer (score 0):

This sounds a bit like a shopping question, however it's pretty easy to buy **DC-DC converters** for 300V more or less  output. Just shop at your favorite distributor.
They tend to be a bit pricey.

Nobody (most likely) is going to want as low a current as you want, so probably something in the 1W range would be the minimum.

To monitor the current on the low side is easy, on the high side I think I'd be tempted to measure the current with an op-amp powered near the 300V output and convert it to something more hefty such as 0-100uA for 0-300nA and then receive with a resistor to ground.